# How to set position fix horizontal and sticky vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having actually a problem. I'm developing a website for my university.

There you have on top a typical header. Below this header is a div with some filter possibility to filter a table, which is positioned below.

The table is typically very large. So you have to scroll sometimes in both directions (horizontal and vertical). If you want to scroll, then should the header stay on its position. Between Header and filter div is a headline located. This headline should hide.

The filters should move a little bit to the top and then stay below the Header. For this, I used `position: sticky`. This works very well.

But if I scroll to the right, the filters move out of the viewport.

So is there a possibility, that the filter div is vertically sticky and stays horizontally in his fixed position?

Here is an example of my problem:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.header {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}



th {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">
Header
</div>
<div class="body">
  <h2>
    Headline
  </h2>
  <div class="filter">
    Filters
  </div>
  <span>some text</span>
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>a</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I don't want to lose the vertical sticky behavior when I scroll horizontal. I want to use sticky vertical and fixed horizontal at the same time.

Comment: Can you show your codes here?

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: we are here to solve the problem here so please ask your questions with some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested:

I've got it done! The solution was to set a specific width. Not a relative width like 100%.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Fix this with simple CSS. Below Code

**.filter {position: fixed;top: 76px;}**

Comment: this doesn't work. I want that it sticks below header when I scroll vertically and stays in position when I scroll horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x: auto;` for `body` class and set `top: 20px; left: 0;` for `filter` class.

Hope this is the solution that you are looking for.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.header {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}



th {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
  Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <h2>
      Headline
    </h2>
    <div class="filter">
      Filters
    </div>
    <span>some text</span>
    <div class="table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi Nitheesh, thanks for your help, but now the filters aren't sticky in the vertical direction anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a little css and everything works:)

```
.table {
   overflow-x:auto;
}
```